# A solid tutorial for Sencha Touch V2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I found a great tutorial on creating an [MVC App from Scratch](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/mobile-development/creating-a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-from-scratch-part-1/) using Sencha Touch V1.1 but unfortunately it isn't all that applicable to Sencha Touch V2. I want to learn the new/right way to build an MVC app moving forward with their latest framework.

Any good tutorial for building an MVC App using Sencha Touch V2?

Here's a list of places I've already looked.

- [Official Docs](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/)

  - Videos are outdated
  - Examples don't show `source` snippets, you have to "View Source" and try to wade through the compressed/minified versions of the library.
  - Documentation doesn't describe MVC at all (just try searching for "mvc" in their search field... you'll come up empty handed)
- [Google Advanced Search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mvc%20%22sencha%20touch%22&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=JL3&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&num=10&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=off&tbs=,qdr:w)

  - I tried narrowing down the results by looking for "Sencha Touch" "mvc" where the articles were posted in the last week.
- And of course [sencha-touch-2](/questions/tagged/sencha-touch-2) right here on StackOverflow.

  - looks like as of this post, I'm the only person posting with that tag

Comment: Introduction to Sencha Touch: http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/01/introduction-to-sencha-touch.html This example uses the Developer Preview of Sencha Touch 2.0.

Comment: Here's my MVC tutorial in another SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229849/sencha-touch-2-0-mvc-tutorial/9247251#9247251

Comment: Funny, this question was closed as not constructive yet it's the highest voted sencha-touch-2 question.

Comment: Some rules on stack are pretty bad,closing questions just because they don't have codes..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have a complete starter-project for Touch 2 using the MVC pattern on github here:

https://github.com/FrancisShanahan/SenchaTouch2MVCHelloworld

You can read my blog post about it here:

http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/sencha-touch-2-0-mvc-in-5-minutes-or-less/

Hope this helps you get started,
-fs

Comment: If you're having trouble getting that example working move the view definition (views: ['Home', 'SimpleList'],) from the controller to the app.js.

Answer (score 6):

I found this link and site very useful - http://miamicoder.com/category/tutorials/sencha-touch-tutorials/

Updated for V2 as well - http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/

Comment: Yes, very helpful for V1.1 information.

Comment: miamicoder tuts are damn good... i love his st2 tuts

Answer (score 4):

I was also looking for such kind of a tutorial and I found this example to be very helpful for kickstarting my own senchatouch 2.0 app: https://github.com/kawanoshinobu/SenchaTouch2-simple-CRUD-sample

It's in python and the author uses google app engine to run it, but it's pretty self-explanatory how you can run a copy locally using any other backend :) Hope this helps

Comment: Great. First Sencha Touch 2 app I've seen running on Google Appengine.

Answer (score 1):

All Sencha products (Sencha Touch, Ext JS) are expected to follow the new MVC architecture. You should start with understand it. Here is my resource list:

1. [MVC Application Architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture)
2. [Getting Started with Touch](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started)
3. [Class System](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/class_system), [Components](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/components) etc..
4. Examples.. but I don't think there are MVC examples for now...

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. In my question I stated that I've already looked through the Getting Started with Touch docs, but there is nothing with MVC, and unfortunately a lot of the examples are still on 1.1 (which is odd that they're in the 2.0 documentation)

Comment: its still in developer preview.. I think we will see more documentation and examples by the time of release.. :)

Comment: Yep, I absolutely get that... just thought there might be someone out there already developing tutorials. I'll roll with what I can find for now. Thanks.

Comment: the Ext JS stuff is good for me to look at. Didn't know they were moving towards unifying the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Start with http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started
and examples/getting_started folder of the Sencha Touch 2.0 SDK download

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but I already looked through there. Doing a search brings up nothing "MVC" related, and lots of the examples in there are still on 1.1