# Basic program in sencha touch & PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I follow the tutorial on  http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/ . and I found a problem at  I can not see the result of the display <'launch'> and when I searched, I found that Ext . regApplication () has-been removed??
I use: cordova-1.8.1.js
and sencha touch version 2.0.1.1

thank's in advance

Comment: By the way, your question is answered you need to accept the right answer by click on the check symbol next to the answer. it's a way of thanking the guy who found the answer.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation :s

Comment: Vote up != Accept. Accept needs 1 reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you're trying to follow is made for Sencha Touch 1. There are quite a few difference between ST1 and ST2. Therefore, I suggest you try the answers of these different posts :

[Sencha Touch 2.0 MVC tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229849/sencha-touch-2-0-mvc-tutorial)

[I need help finding a solid tutorial for Sencha Touch V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816305/i-need-help-finding-a-solid-tutorial-for-sencha-touch-v2)

Hope this helps